# How to add each line into single line in txt file Perl?

Tags: perl

I have problem with my code cose of this part:

```
foreach my $line(keys %results){
     print Dump($post) if $results{$line} == 1;
}
```

I need it to be only one time printed 'print Dump($post)'

Here is all that part

```
my $f1 = "/home/shaman/Desktop/data.txt";
my $f2 = "/home/shaman/Desktop/ini.txt";


my %results = (); 
open FILE1, "$f1" or die "Could not open file: $! \n";

while(my $line = <FILE1>){
    $results{$line}=1;
}
close(FILE1); 


open FILE2, "$f2" or die "Could not open file: $! \n";
while(my $line =<FILE2>) {  
    $results{$line}++;
}
close(FILE2);  

foreach my $line(keys %results){
    print Dump($post) if $results{$line} == 1;
}
```

$post contains same like it lines but cose of hash I get randomed lines if i print line by line...

If I run code it will repat printed post 4-5 times it depends how much lines have in it post(lines comes dinamicly) but I need post be printed just one time...

Comment: What problem are you having at the moment?

Comment: You are trying to find the lines that are in `data.txt` but not in `ini.txt`, right?

Comment: You have not assigned anything to the variable `$post` that you are dumping. So if you run this code as it is, it will just print a bunch of empty (undefined) lines.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
my $dump_done = 0;
foreach my $line(keys %results){
    if ($results{$line} == 1 and !$dump_done) {
        print Dump($post);
        $dump_done = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to print just once, as long as at least one line of your results equals one.

If that is correct, you can make this simple modification to your code:

```
foreach my $line(keys %results){
     if ($results{$line} == 1)
     {
          print Dump($post);
          last;
     }
}
```

This will exit the loop as soon as you find one match.

If you need to complete the whole loop for other reasons, use M42's solution.